# Trouble debugging Android application: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, debugging

I have made my first android app. It works fine locally. But when I upload it to the market, somehow people have problems with it. I cannot figure out what went wrong. Even when I have the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.jphellemons.koopzondag.Koopzondag: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jphellemons.koopzondag.Koopzondag in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.jphellemons.koopzondag-2.apk]
at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:715)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4615)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2223)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jphellemons.koopzondag.Koopzondag in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.jphellemons.koopzondag-2.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:945)
at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:706)
```

Please let me know if i have to show the manifest and/or source code? I really have no idea
I will update this thread if I have the answer!

I have read about this issue here: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on working app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781151/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-on-working-app/3781299#3781299)

So I guess that my fault is a setting in this window: can someone help me out with that?

[image]

Edit: I changed the first class from helloandroid.java to koopzondag.java and now i have the classcastexception. so I renamed the complete project. but now it can't launch the resource?

**edit2** : Looks like this is the issue: but how do I resolve it? http://androidforums.com/application-development/216707-classcastexception-starting-activity.html#post1905263

Comment: What export settings did you use to create the .apk?

Comment: @gatnowurry: I used the default export from eclipse 'Export Android Application' where can I view export settings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android classcastexception on activity startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838640/android-classcastexception-on-activity-startup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer: [android classcastexception on activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838640/android-classcastexception-on-activity-startup/3953239#3953239)

Quote from Maxim:

1. Open `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. Find tag `application`
3. Remove attribute `android:name` (if exists)
4. Add attribute `android:name="android.app.Application"`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using additional jars, you need to add those to the `/libs` folder.

Comment: Hi Macarse, I have them in my lib and right clicked to add it to the build path

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android API Level higher than the phones are supporting, you'll get Runtime exceptions.

You seem to use API Level 8, have you specified the right levels in the manifest file?

Comment: I had it at seven, now changed it to 8 and still have the same error: `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" android:minSdkVersion="8"></uses-sdk>`