# Android Device Infomation - Application Crashing Out onCreate

Tags: android, network-programming

When I run my app it crash out can anybody help me out and guide me in the correct direction of making this code work?

```
public class DeviceInfoActivity extends Activity {

        private static final String APP_NAME = "SignalLevelSample";
        private static final int EXCELLENT_LEVEL = 75;
        private static final int GOOD_LEVEL = 50;
        private static final int MODERATE_LEVEL = 25;
        private static final int WEAK_LEVEL = 0;

        private static final int INFO_SERVICE_STATE_INDEX = 0;
        private static final int INFO_CELL_LOCATION_INDEX = 1;
        private static final int INFO_CALL_STATE_INDEX = 2;
        private static final int INFO_CONNECTION_STATE_INDEX = 3;
        private static final int INFO_SIGNAL_LEVEL_INDEX = 4;
        private static final int INFO_SIGNAL_LEVEL_INFO_INDEX = 5;
        private static final int INFO_DATA_DIRECTION_INDEX = 6;
        private static final int INFO_DEVICE_INFO_INDEX = 7;

        private static final int[] info_ids= {
                R.id.serviceState_info,
                R.id.cellLocation_info,
                R.id.callState_info,
                R.id.connectionState_info,
                R.id.signalLevel,
                R.id.signalLevelInfo,
                R.id.dataDirection,
                R.id.device_info
        };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        startSignalLevelListener();
        displayTelephonyInfo();
    }


    @Override
        protected void onPause()
        {
                super.onPause();

                stopListening();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume()
        {
                super.onResume();

                startSignalLevelListener();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy()
        {
                stopListening();

                super.onDestroy();
        }

        private void setTextViewText(int id,String text) {
                ((TextView)findViewById(id)).setText(text);
        }

        private void setSignalLevel(int id,int infoid,int level){
                int progress = (int) ((((float)level)/31.0) * 100);
                String signalLevelString = getSignalLevelString(progress);

                ((ProgressBar)findViewById(id)).setProgress(progress);
                ((TextView)findViewById(infoid)).setText(signalLevelString);

                Log.i("signalLevel ","" + progress);
        }

        private String getSignalLevelString(int level) {
                String signalLevelString = "Weak";

                if(level > EXCELLENT_LEVEL)             signalLevelString = "Excellent";
                else if(level > GOOD_LEVEL)             signalLevelString = "Good";
                else if(level > MODERATE_LEVEL) signalLevelString = "Moderate";
                else if(level > WEAK_LEVEL)             signalLevelString = "Weak";

                return signalLevelString;
        }

        private void stopListening(){
                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                tm.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        }

        private void setDataDirection(int id, int direction){
                int resid = getDataDirectionRes(direction);

                ((ImageView)findViewById(id)).setImageResource(resid);
        }

        private int getDataDirectionRes(int direction){
                int resid = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

                switch(direction)
                {
                        case TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_IN:         resid = R.drawable.ic_launcher; break;
                        case TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_OUT:        resid = R.drawable.ic_launcher; break;
                        case TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_INOUT:      resid = R.drawable.ic_launcher; break;
                        case TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_NONE:       resid = R.drawable.ic_launcher; break;
                        default:                                        resid = R.drawable.ic_launcher; break;
                }

                return resid;
        }

        private void startSignalLevelListener() {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int events = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTH | 
                                 PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_ACTIVITY | 
                                 PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION |
                                 PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE |
                                 PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_FORWARDING_INDICATOR |
                                 PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE |
                                 PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_MESSAGE_WAITING_INDICATOR |
                                 PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE;

        tm.listen(phoneStateListener, events);
    }

        private void displayTelephonyInfo(){
                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                GsmCellLocation loc = (GsmCellLocation) tm.getCellLocation();

                int cellid = loc.getCid();
                int lac = loc.getLac();

                String deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();
                String phonenumber = tm.getLine1Number();
                String softwareversion = tm.getDeviceSoftwareVersion();
                String operatorname = tm.getNetworkOperatorName();
                String simcountrycode = tm.getSimCountryIso();
                String simoperator = tm.getSimOperatorName();
                String simserialno = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
                String subscriberid = tm.getSubscriberId();
                String networktype = getNetworkTypeString(tm.getNetworkType());
                String phonetype = getPhoneTypeString(tm.getPhoneType());

                logString("CellID: " + cellid);
                logString("LAC: " + lac);
                logString("Device ID: " + deviceid);
                logString("Phone Number: " + phonenumber);
                logString("Software Version: " + softwareversion);
                logString("Operator Name: " + operatorname);
                logString("SIM Country Code: " + simcountrycode);
                logString("SIM Operator: " + simoperator);
                logString("SIM Serial No.: " + simserialno);
                logString("Sibscriber ID: " + subscriberid);

                String deviceinfo = "";

                deviceinfo += ("CellID: " + cellid + "\n");
                deviceinfo += ("LAC: " + lac + "\n");
                deviceinfo += ("Device ID: " + deviceid + "\n");
                deviceinfo += ("Phone Number: " + phonenumber + "\n");
                deviceinfo += ("Software Version: " + softwareversion + "\n");
                deviceinfo += ("Operator Name: " + operatorname + "\n");
                deviceinfo += ("SIM Country Code: " + simcountrycode + "\n");
                deviceinfo += ("SIM Operator: " + simoperator + "\n");
                deviceinfo += ("SIM Serial No.: " + simserialno + "\n");
                deviceinfo += ("Subscriber ID: " + subscriberid + "\n");
                deviceinfo += ("Network Type: " + networktype + "\n");
                deviceinfo += ("Phone Type: " + phonetype + "\n");

                List<NeighboringCellInfo> cellinfo = tm.getNeighboringCellInfo();

                if(null != cellinfo){
                        for(NeighboringCellInfo info: cellinfo){
                                deviceinfo += ("\tCellID: " + info.getCid() + ", RSSI: " + info.getRssi() + "\n");
                        }
                }

                setTextViewText(info_ids[INFO_DEVICE_INFO_INDEX],deviceinfo);
        }

        private String getNetworkTypeString(int type){
                String typeString = "Unknown";

                switch(type)
                {
                        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:        typeString = "EDGE"; break;
                        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:        typeString = "GPRS"; break;
                        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:        typeString = "UMTS"; break;
                        default:                                                                        typeString = "UNKNOWN"; break;
                }

                return typeString;
        }

        private String getPhoneTypeString(int type){
                String typeString = "Unknown";

                switch(type)
                {
                        case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM:   typeString = "GSM"; break;
                        case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE:  typeString = "UNKNOWN"; break;
                        default:                                                                typeString = "UNKNOWN"; break;
                }

                return typeString;
        }

        private int logString(String message) {
                return Log.i(APP_NAME,message);
        }

    private final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener(){

                @Override
                public void onCallForwardingIndicatorChanged(boolean cfi)
                {
                        Log.i(APP_NAME, "onCallForwardingIndicatorChanged " + cfi);

                        super.onCallForwardingIndicatorChanged(cfi);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
                {
                        String callState = "UNKNOWN";

                        switch(state)
                        {
                                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:          callState = "IDLE"; break;
                                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:       callState = "Ringing (" + incomingNumber + ")"; break;
                                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:       callState = "Offhook"; break;
                        }

                        setTextViewText(info_ids[INFO_CALL_STATE_INDEX],callState);

                        Log.i(APP_NAME, "onCallStateChanged " + callState);

                        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation location)
                {
                        String locationString = location.toString();

                        setTextViewText(info_ids[INFO_CELL_LOCATION_INDEX],locationString);

                        Log.i(APP_NAME, "onCellLocationChanged " + locationString);

                        super.onCellLocationChanged(location);
                }

                @Override
                public void onDataActivity(int direction)
                {
                        String directionString = "none";

                        switch(direction)
                        {
                                case TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_IN:         directionString = "IN"; break;
                                case TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_OUT:        directionString = "OUT"; break;
                                case TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_INOUT:      directionString = "INOUT"; break;
                                case TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_NONE:       directionString = "NONE"; break;
                                default:                                                                        directionString = "UNKNOWN: " + direction; break;
                        }

                        setDataDirection(info_ids[INFO_DATA_DIRECTION_INDEX],direction);

                        Log.i(APP_NAME, "onDataActivity " + directionString);

                        super.onDataActivity(direction);
                }

                @Override
                public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state)
                {
                        String connectionState = "Unknown";

                        switch(state)
                        {
                                case TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED:           connectionState = "Connected"; break;
                                case TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTING:          connectionState = "Connecting"; break;
                                case TelephonyManager.DATA_DISCONNECTED:        connectionState = "Disconnected"; break;
                                case TelephonyManager.DATA_SUSPENDED:           connectionState = "Suspended"; break;
                                default:                                                                        connectionState = "Unknown: " + state; break;
                        }

                        setTextViewText(info_ids[INFO_CONNECTION_STATE_INDEX],connectionState);

                        Log.i(APP_NAME, "onDataConnectionStateChanged " + connectionState);

                        super.onDataConnectionStateChanged(state);
                }

                @Override
                public void onMessageWaitingIndicatorChanged(boolean mwi)
                {
                        Log.i(APP_NAME, "onMessageWaitingIndicatorChanged " + mwi);

                        super.onMessageWaitingIndicatorChanged(mwi);
                }

                @Override
                public void onServiceStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState)
                {
                        String serviceStateString = "UNKNOWN";

                        switch(serviceState.getState())
                        {
                                case ServiceState.STATE_IN_SERVICE:             serviceStateString = "IN SERVICE"; break;
                                case ServiceState.STATE_EMERGENCY_ONLY:         serviceStateString = "EMERGENCY ONLY"; break;
                                case ServiceState.STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE:         serviceStateString = "OUT OF SERVICE"; break;
                                case ServiceState.STATE_POWER_OFF:                      serviceStateString = "POWER OFF"; break;
                                default:                                                                        serviceStateString = "UNKNOWN"; break;
                        }

                        setTextViewText(info_ids[INFO_SERVICE_STATE_INDEX],serviceStateString);

                        Log.i(APP_NAME, "onServiceStateChanged " + serviceStateString);

                        super.onServiceStateChanged(serviceState);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSignalStrengthChanged(int asu)
                {
                        Log.i(APP_NAME, "onSignalStrengthChanged " + asu);

                        setSignalLevel(info_ids[INFO_SIGNAL_LEVEL_INDEX],info_ids[INFO_SIGNAL_LEVEL_INFO_INDEX],asu);

                        super.onSignalStrengthChanged(asu);
                }
    };
}
```

//========================
xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false">

        <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView android:text="Serivice State" style="@style/labelStyleRight"/>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/serviceState_info" style="@style/textStyle"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView android:text="Cell Location" style="@style/labelStyleRight"/>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/cellLocation_info" style="@style/textStyle"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView android:text="Call State" style="@style/labelStyleRight"/>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/callState_info" style="@style/textStyle"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView android:text="Connection State" style="@style/labelStyleRight"/>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/connectionState_info" style="@style/textStyle"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView android:text="Signal Level" style="@style/labelStyleRight"/>

                        <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/signalLevel" style="@style/progressStyle"/>
                                <TextView android:id="@+id/signalLevelInfo" style="@style/textSmallStyle"/>
                        </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView android:text="Data" style="@style/labelStyleRight"/>
                        <ImageView android:id="@+id/dataDirection" style="@style/imageStyle"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/device_info" style="@style/labelStyleLeft"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

//=================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sirisak.phone"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".DeviceInfoActivity "
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: the catlog reads "Unable to start Activity" and I am using a Actual Device.

Comment: Did you put the activity in the manifest.xml file?

Comment: Here is the manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".DeviceInfoActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: I am attempting to run this as a single activity at this time and add it to another project after the Activity proves successful

Comment: Can you post the entire logcat?

Comment: Here is a picture http://sphotos.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/539887_3245978904978_1132070081_32411871_1897199421_n.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add:

```
android:name="android.app.Application"
```

to the `application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

This is because you have a ClassCastException. See: [android classcastexception on activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838640/android-classcastexception-on-activity-startup)

Comment: I don't see it in the manifest you posted. You have to put it in the application tag, not the activity tag.

Comment: this is a single activity ... what is the correct way to write this manifest?

Comment: The way you have is fine (I'm assuming that's not your entire manifest..it's missing a few closing tags). Just add this to the <application> tag.

Comment: my tags are present they just didn't attach to the post

Comment: ... Did you add it to the application tag?

Comment: Yes I did and the app still crashes ... shall I send you all the files in a .zip?

Comment: Yes the error is still the same per the catlog and I have no clue what I am doing wrong.